# Using template views in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I have some XML view files. They have some common parts. For example `customHeaderContent` in the following piece of code repeated in many other pages. Is possible somehow transfer these parts to a template file and them from there. I know fragment view files. But I don't know how to aggregate common parts in XML files and attach them to different views.

```
<mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic" xmlns:footerbar="sap.ushell.ui.footerbar" controllerName="xyz.controller.Worklist" afterRendering="onInit">
<semantic:FullscreenPage id="page" navButtonPress="onNavBack" showNavButton="true" title="{i18n>worklistViewTitle}">
    <semantic:content>
        .....
    </semantic:content>
    <semantic:customHeaderContent>
        <Button icon="images/de.svg" width="auto" id="__button_lang" tooltip="{i18n>lang_de}" press="onChangeLangBtnPress"/>
    </semantic:customHeaderContent>
</semantic:FullscreenPage>
```

Comment: Read https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/df8c9c3d79b54c928855162bafcd88ee.html and https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/4da72985139b4b83b5f1c1e0c0d2ed5a.html

Comment: @Marc Thanks was helpful. But I found my answer here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/234320f8d8ee45b39c60893116d60351.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/234320f8d8ee45b39c60893116d60351.html) provided by the OP may be erased in the future so here is the gist of the answer there.

Refer to your fragment XML views using the Fragment declaration of sap.ui.core, as example below where the 'my.useful.SimpleUiPart' view is being used:

```
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:commons="sap.ui.commons" controllerName="testdata.fragments.XMLViewController" >

    <commons:HorizontalDivider />

    <core:Fragment               fragmentName="my.useful.SimpleUiPart" type="XML" />
    <core:Fragment id="xmlInXml" fragmentName="my.useful.SimpleUiPart" type="XML" />

    <commons:HorizontalDivider />

</mvc:View>
```

Comment: @MahdiJaberzadeh think about people who come to this post in 2 years time when that link to SAPUI5 tutorial is no longer working. I edited the example code to make it a precise answer.